Unable to restrict access to Tomcat by IP address
I'm running Tomcat 10.1.26 on Ubuntu 20.04, and I'm attempting to restrict access to a specific webapp by IP address. I have looked at these articles, followed their instructions, and cannot get it to work:

How to restrict access by IP address with Tomcat?

Restrict tomcat access by ip

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/config/filter.html#Remote_Address_Filter


In /opt/tomcat/conf/server.xml, I have this entry:
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
       unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

       <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
              allow="192\.168\.\d+\.\d+"
              deny=".*" />

       <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
              prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
              pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

</Host>

This should allow access only to 192.168.x.x IP addresses and deny access to all others, yet access from any IP address is restricted. I have tried the following:

Using this RemoteAddrValve:
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
       allow="192\.168\.\d+\.\d+" />

In this case, the web app is accessible from any IP address. The "allow" entry appears to be ignored.

Using this RemoteAddrValve:
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
       deny=".*" />

In this case, the web app cannot be accessed from any IP address, which tells me the valve is working.

I've used this RemoteAddrValve using the specific internal IP address for a workstation, thinking maybe the format for the IP address range was wrong. I also tried it with a specific external IP address:
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
       allow="192\.168\.10\.109" />

In this case, access from any IP address was allowed. Again, the "allow" entry appeared to be ignored.

Added the valve to the /opt/tomcat/conf/content.xml instead of the server.xml as some comments in the above articles suggested to do. This failed.

Added the valve to /<mywebapp>/META-INF/content.xml as some comments suggested to do. This caused the webapp to fail to load.


I'm out of ideas and hoping someone here can identify the issue.
